# Show there is a homomorphism from $G/N$ onto $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\sigma: G \to K$ be an epimorphism (onto homomorphism). And let $N$ be a subgroup of $\ker( )$ that $N \triangleright G$. Show there is a homomorphism from $G/N$ onto $K$. Note that if $N=\ker(\sigma)$, this is an isomorphism.

If I knew that $N=\ker(\sigma)$. Then I can do the proof.

This is because of the universal property of quotient spaces.

> If $f:G\to H$ is a continuous surjection between spaces, $R$ is an equivalence relation on $G$, and $f$ respects the relation, i.e. $f(g)=f(g')$ whenever $gRg'$, then we have a unique continuous surjection $\tilde f: G/R\to H$ such that $\tilde f\circ q=f$ where $q:G\to G/R$ is the canonical surjection. If $f(g)=f(g')$ if and **only if** $gRg'$, then $\tilde f$ is a bijection. And if $f$ is open or closed (or more generally a quotient map), then $\tilde f$ is a homeomorphism.

In the case of groups $G,H$ and a normal subgroup $N\le G$, we have a relation $R$ by $gRg'$ whenever $g^{-1}g'\in N$. The equivalence classes are simply the cosets $gN$. If $N=\ker(f)$, then $f(g)=f(g')\iff gN=g'N$, so you have a continuous isomorphism $\tilde f:G/N\to H$ (Note that it is a homomorphism by the first isomophism theorem of groups). As $f$ is open, $\tilde f$ is a homeomorphism.

What I need help with is showing that $N=\ker(\sigma)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you quoted is about topological spaces and the result you want to prove is about groups. The quoted result does not apply unless the groups are topological groups. Even if they are topological groups, the quoted result will not help you solve the problem. You want to use the isomorphism theorems of groups to find a proof.